# Trying to write a program that checks if a string is an isogram with javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried the code below below, passed few tests and failed others.

```
 function isIsogram(str) {
    //...
    var strArr = str;
    for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < strArr.length; i++) {
            if (strArr[i] == strArr[j]) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
isIsogram("isaac");
```

Comment: Would you mind telling which tests it failed?

Comment: Your function returns on the first comparison it performs. The `return` statement exits the function **immediately**.

Comment: @JJJ It failed the following: 
aharevqxngkldib
gsmdskpfwjxzonlbqrhatyveiuc
otzbwulhpszmcayxgvjrnfed

Answer (score 4):

Never forget how powerful regexes are!

```
function isIsogram(str){ 
  return !/(\w).*\1/i.test(str)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to exclude the current char in your code please check this

```
function isIsogram(str) {
//...
var strArr = str;
for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < strArr.length; j++) {
        if(i!=j){
          if (strArr[i] == strArr[j]) {
              return false
          }
        }
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second loop you are incrementin `i`, not `j`. Also the function should return `false` on a match and should avoid checking `strArr[i]` with itself...

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

```js
function isIsogram(str) {

 var word = str.split(''); //split the word into an array
 for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < word.length - 1; i++, j++) {
   if (word[i] == word[j]){//check if the character right after the current is the same
                              //as the current character
     console.log('Not');
     return false;      //if it is - it's not an isogram
   }
 }
 console.log('Isogram');
 return true;   //loop has passed - it's an isogram
}

isIsogram("isaac");
isIsogram("isac");
```

Simplier method:

```js
function isIsogram(word){
   word = word.split('');
   word.every((v,i) => v != word[i-1]) ? console.log('Isogram') : console.log('Not');
}

isIsogram('isaac');
isIsogram('isac');
```

Comment: This is a different definition of isograms than OP seems to be asking about, wherein the duplicate letter isn't allowed anywhere in the string, not just adjacent characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isogram(a){    
    let b = Array.from(new Set(a)).join('');
    if (a==b){
        return true;
    } return false
};

isogram('David'); //true

isogram('Davidi');  //false
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: thank you @jay.sf, I would find time to explain this later

Comment: Why not just `return new Set(a).size === a.length`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function isogram(wrd) {
    if (typeof wrd !== "string" || wrd.length === 0) return false;

    wrd = wrd.trim().toLowerCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < wrd.length; i++) {
            if (wrd.lastIndexOf(wrd[i]) > i) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's good to add explanation to say how your code addresses the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Isogram(str){
    let myStr = str.toLowerCase();
    let mySet = new Set();

    for(let i = 0; i < myStr.length; i++){
        if(mySet.has(myStr[i])){
            return false;
            break;
        }
        else{
            mySet.add(myStr[i]);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here, I use a Set. The logic is - for each characters in the string, if the character is present in the Set then the string will not be a isogram.

I check if the character is present in the set, if not present then i will add the new character into the set. when the character repeats in future iterations, I will be having it already in the Set and on comparing with values in Set and on finding the copy i will return 'false'